# What can make a ffllush take seconds

Tags: linux, stdout, flush

I have a very basic code running, something like this (I tried both Python and C):

```
for (;;) {
    fprintf(f, strftime());
    fflush(f);
    sleep(1);
}
```

I must have something wrong somewhere in my system, because the time difference between two consecutive lines in the logs is sometimes literally **tenths of seconds**!

What kind of long running process can a `fflush` trigger?

PS: The file being opened is on a local drive.

edit:

An extract of `strace -tt` log:

```
12:12:42.664505 rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD], [], 8) = 0
12:12:42.664571 rt_sigaction(SIGCHLD, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
12:12:42.664595 rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
12:12:42.664614 nanosleep({1, 0}, 0x7fff3c26fad0) = 0
12:12:43.664818 stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
12:12:43.664944 write(3, "2016-03-17 12:12:43\n", 20) = 20
12:12:43.665018 rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD], [], 8) = 0
12:12:43.665102 rt_sigaction(SIGCHLD, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
12:12:43.665168 rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
12:12:43.665217 nanosleep({1, 0}, 0x7fff3c26fad0) = 0
12:12:49.789302 stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
12:12:49.789430 write(3, "2016-03-17 12:12:49\n", 20) = 20
12:12:49.789495 rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD], [], 8) = 0
12:12:49.789549 rt_sigaction(SIGCHLD, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
12:12:49.789605 rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
12:12:49.789648 nanosleep({1, 0}, 0x7fff3c26fad0) = 0
12:12:50.946087 stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
12:12:50.946201 write(3, "2016-03-17 12:12:50\n", 20) = 20
12:12:50.946273 rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD], [], 8) = 0
```

I'm confused, because I extracted this very simple test from a more complicated example with no wait but a flush clearly taking time, although here it seems that the issue comes from `nanosleep` taking too long.

Comment: Try running your application under `strace -tt` to see more details.

Comment: The drop occurs between the call to `nanosleep` and `stat(/etc/localtime)` so maybe the issue is with the wait.

Comment: There could be a high priority process preempting yours.

Comment: Please tag with the language

Comment: @123 which language? The most appropriate here would be "linux" I guess... What I gave is pseudo-code.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin The high demanding tasks run with a lower priority (nice 10 vs nice 0 for my test)

Comment: It looks like `nanosleep` returns two seconds late, does it not? That suggests that this is system's performance issue.